# Accessing form control from within a thread using delegates in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates, controls

I have a problem in updating the form control from a thread using a delegate.

This is the flow I use.

Dashboard Screen(parent mdi window) -> QuizScreen (child Mdi Window) 
Once in QuizScreen A thread is started and that thread code is kept in a module(server.vb). 
From this thread I need to find and update a control(which is dynamically created)

Following is the delegate code i call from inside a thread

```
Public Sub ChangePictImage(ByVal ipaddress As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim del As NodeDelegate
        del = AddressOf ChangePictImage
        Me.Invoke(del, ipaddress)
        'Return
    Else
        Me.BackColor = Color.Green
        Me.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\images\application-on.png")
    End If


    Dim centerFlowPanel As FlowLayoutPanel = CType(QuizScreen.centerFlowPanel, FlowLayoutPanel)
    Dim computerIconsPanel As FlowLayoutPanel = CType(centerFlowPanel.Controls("computerIconsPanel"), FlowLayoutPanel)
    Dim flowpanel As FlowLayoutPanel = CType(computerIconsPanel.Controls("flow_" + ipaddress), FlowLayoutPanel)
    Dim pictControl As PictureBox = CType(flowpanel.Controls("pict_" + ipaddress), PictureBox)
    pictControl.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\images\application-on.png")
End Sub
```

I call this delegate from inside the thread as follows

```
threadData.dashboard.ChangePictImage(ipAddress)
```

As you may have noticed, I have put the delegate sub in dashboad.vb

I am able to find the elements to the deepest level. Infact I can alert their name and other properties
But when I try to set something. It doesn't do anything.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Hi all, Just to let you know, If I alert MsgBox(pictControl.Name.toString) it works. The code posted above works without errors. But it doesnt do anything. No object not set to reference errors or cross thread errors. Somebody please please help

Comment: Ok I think I am out of luck. God save me.

Comment: I dont know why nobody is replying. Well I am thanking people in advance. :)